# Concise way to loop list of dictionaries and store key-value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of dictionaries and want to store the  key-value pairs then create a pandas dataframe from this.

For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for data in list_of_dictionary:
    for key, values in data.items():
        dictionary[key].append(values)
pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

This works, however, I have to apply this same loop to a number of independent data items, therefore, is there a concise way to implement this for-loop, perhaps in one-line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can for instance, use a list comprehension along with the pd.DataFrame() constructor as follows.

```
list_of_dict = [...]  # Your list of dictionaries

df = pd.DataFrame({key: [d.get(key) for d in list_of_dict] for key in set().union(*list_of_dict)})
```

So, Here, `set().union(*list_of_dictionary)` combines all the keys from the dictionaries in `list_of_dict` into a single set (with no duplicated values).

and `{key: [d.get(key) for d in list_of_dictionary] for key in set().union(*list_of_dictionary)}` is a dictionary comprehension. First, it iterates over each key in the set. It then creates a dictionary where the key is the column name and the value is a list comprehension that retrieves the corresponding value for each dictionary in `list_of_dict`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list_of_dict)
```

Check from_records method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html